# Partial Search Spring MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Mongo provides a text search feature. It returns a match if a whole word is found. I want to search for a partial word to provide a predictive search. I am saving full queries in my mongodb.

For example, tesla model 3 might be a full-text query, tesla model x might be another. when the user enters tesla, i want to return a list of queries relating to the search.

e.g. the user enters tesla, I want to return tesla model 3 and tesla model x as predictions.

I am using Spring Framework for Java. Spring Data MongoDB.

Still trying to figure out how to approach this, so no code yet.

Comment: Atlas or self-managed cluster? If the former then that's what Atlas Search is for. If the latter then regex is the simplest but very slow, manual tokenization could be an option but is more difficult to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlas Search is likely what you are looking for, specifically support for Partial Match queries.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/partial-match/.

The Spring Data MongoDB documentation also include a code snippet to get started with Atlas Search. Check out the "Tip" section of this page:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/4.0.0-RC1/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.supported-aggregation-operations